# Let $f(x)$ be $q$ continuous and differentiable with $f(r)=f^{(1)}(r)=...=f^{(q-1)}(r)=0$ and $f^{(q)}(r)\neq 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

**Problem:**
Let $f(x)$ be $q$ continuous and differentiable with $f(r)=f^{(1)}(r)=...=f^{(q-1)}(r)=0$ and $f^{(q)}(r)\neq 0.$ Show that
$$u(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$$
fulfills
$$u'(r)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow r} \frac{u(x)}{x-r}=\frac{1}{q}\neq 0.$$

**Attempt:**
I have tried to use Taylor series on $f$ and $f'$ such that:
$$f(x)=f(r)+f'(r)(x-r)+...+\frac{f^{(q)}(r)}{q!}(x-r)^q$$
and
$$f'(x)=f'(r)+f''(r)(x-r)+...+q\cdot \frac{f^{(q-1)}(r)}{(q-1)!}(x-r)^{q-1}$$

But when i put in the formula given i keep end up dividing by zero, because $f^{(q-1)}(r)=0.$

Another attempt is that i'm trying to use MVT, but i then again run into the problem that i don't know anything about $f'(\xi).$

Any hints out there?

Comment: Check again how degree and order relate in $f'$. // You could also just factorize $f(x)=(x-r)^qg(x)$ with $g(r)\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition you mention means that $r$ is a root with multiplicity $q$ and so you can use the factorisation $f(x)= (x-r)^{q} \phi(x)$, where $\phi(x) \ne 0$ in a neighbourhood of $r$.

$$
\lim_{x\to r}\frac{u(x)}{x-r} = \lim_{x\to r}\frac{(x-r)^q \phi(x)}{(x-r)(q(x-r)^{q-1} \phi (x) + (x-r)^q)\phi'(x)}=\lim_{x\to r}\dfrac{\phi(x)}{q \phi(x) + (x-r)\phi'(x)} = \frac{1}{q}.
$$